# How to call a function from a class other than MainActivity on button click in Android Java

Tags: java, android, onclick

I want to call a function on a button click in Android. All the examples so far seem to only be able to call it from `MainActivity.java`, but I want to call it from a different class. How would I do this?

I've tried calling it from `activity_main.xml` using `android:on_click="myfunction()"`, but this is only able to be called from `MainActivity.java`. I've also tried using an `onClick` listener, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So far I have this:

```
Button onoroff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.activate);
onoroff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick()
    {
        myfunction();
    }
});
```

But this is showing:

```
; Expected
```

Over here `onClick() *here* {`.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, or if there is another way, or if I did not format this correctly. All I want to do is when the button is pressed, it will call `myfunction()`. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Attach your function code, the snippet you attached so far looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
onoroff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               myfunction();
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is great, but it only works in MainActivity.java. I need it to work in a different java class

Comment: And if I try to call Differentclass.myfunction(), I get a Non-static method 'myfunction()' cannot be referenced from a static context error. If I can call that function from MainActivity, then the above code is fine, and I just need a way to call the function from MainActivity without getting this error.

Comment: you call the function through class name then this function must be static member like that " public static return_type myfunction()  {  }" in that different class or you can make instance  of that class and call your non static function

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick function isn't overriding properly...incorrect method signature and no @Override annotation (look at Hussein Bilal's answer). Good way to avoid this is using the auto-complete Android Studio provides.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the simplified lambda form of the `setOnClickListener` and it should work if you replace what you have with the following:

```
b.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    myfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the @Override annotation above the onClick function. Well you cannot access static function in a non static method. And if u want to access that function in another class so make that function static and access it with the name of the class in which the function is written. And non static functions can only be called by the instance of that class.